# Implement Great Circle Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, formula, pow, great-circle

Below is a formula (Great Circle algorithm) that I want to be translated into PHP. I would really appreciate if someone would help me with that?

The input is to different sets of coordinates, e.g:

```
Place 1 Lat: 59.389057
Place 1 Long: 17.937422

Place 2 Lat: 59.388914
Place 2 Long: 17.920441
```

The wanted output is the distance between place 1 and place 2.

```
distance = ((115.1666667 * (lat2-lat1)) ^ 2 + (115.1666667 * (lng2 - lng1) * cos(lat2 / 57.3)) ^ 2) ^ .5
```

My try:

```
$distance = pow(((115.1666667 * ($lat2 - $lat1)), 2) + (115.1666667 * pow(($lng2 - $lng1) * cos($lat2 / 57.3)), 2)), 0.5)
```

Comment: Why is your try poor? How could you improve it? How can you test it to show that it is working? Where do you hit the roadblock to translate the formula? What are the input values? What are the expected output values? [delref](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14091549/367456)

Comment: This is a pretty good example of "temporary variables make things easier to read".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DCoder writes in the comments, temporary variables make things easier to read:

```
$latD = (691 / 6) * ($lat2 - $lat1);
$lngD = (691 / 6) * ($lng2 - $lng1) * cos($lat2 / 57.3);

$distance = sqrt( $latD * $latD + $lngD * $lngD );
```

([demo on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/gKIEp635))

Comment: Ps. For a more accurate formula, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Answer (score 1):

Here's the corrected code:

```
$distance = pow((pow((115.1666667 * ($lat2 - $lat1)), 2) + pow((115.1666667 * ($lng2 - $lng1) * cos($lat2 / 57.3)), 2)), 0.5);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There's somethin g wrong with it cause I get an error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' ?

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering about this as I was - the return value is in kilometres.